# git: reset submodule branch to remote tag

Tags: git, tags

I have a main module with tags and I have some submodules under the main module.
I want to reset the main module to a specific tag (example "v2.11.0") and reset the submodules to this tag also. the tag is only in the main module, so it is a remote tag for the submodules.

```
git fetch --all --tags
git reset --hard tags/v2.11.0
git submodule foreach --recursive git checkout -B master
git submodule foreach --recursive git reset --hard tags/v2.11.0
```

Resetting the main module to the tag works. But resetting the submodules to the remote tag doesnt work with the code above.
Do you know whats wrong?

Greetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
git submodule foreach git checkout -f -B master
```

This will set the submodules to the commits which belong to the superproject tag. Afterwards the master branch will be checked out on this commit.

Answer (score 1):

A tag is a name for a commit.  The `tags/v2.11.0` tag in the superproject is therefore a name for—that is, represents the number, or hash ID of—a particular commit in the superproject.  So this:

> ```
> git fetch --all --tags
> git reset --hard tags/v2.11.0
> ```

is a little weird,<sup>1</sup> but not entirely crazy.

Each submodule, though, is a *separate Git repository*.  That separate Git repository may or may not have a tag `v2.11.0`; if it does have such a tag, that tag will represent some *other* commit that exists in that other Git repository:

> the tag is only in the main module ...

I presume that this means that each submodule has no such tag.

> ... so it is a remote tag for the submodules

No, it's not.  There's no such thing as a "remote tag".  A tag is just a name for a commit hash ID, and in any given repository, you either have the tag, or you don't.  If you don't have the tag, you don't have that name.  Some other repository's tag is a name for some hash ID in *that repository*.

Git is all about commits.  Each commit has a unique hash ID.  That's a lot of what you're doing with Git: you might *use* a branch name like `master` or `develop` or whatever, or a tag name like `v2.11.0`, but you're really telling Git *get me commit `b0ff0cab1e...`*.  (The full hash ID is long and ugly, but you can find it with:

```
git rev-parse tags/v2.11.0
```

for instance.)

A normal way to use a superproject is to have, in the superproject commit, the correct hash ID for each submodule.  That's part of the commit itself, as an entity that Git calls a *gitlink*.  Checking out the superproject commit results in putting that gitlink into the superproject Git's index.  That Git's index now holds, as a path-name-and-hash-ID pair like `path/to/submodule` and `feedc0ffee...`, the commit that one might want the submodule to `git checkout` (as a detached HEAD).

If you want to make each submodule be a detached HEAD at that commit, you would now run:

```
git submodule update checkout
```

or:

```
git submodule update --recursive checkout
```

to make the submodule itself recursively check out any of its own submodules.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `--all` option to `git fetch` means *fetch from all remotes*.  This makes a little bit of sense in the context in which you're using it, since each remote could have some set of tags, and this would get your Git to copy *all* of their tags, into a massive tag-union.  If there are conflicts—if remote A says that tag `v1.2.3` should mean `deadbeef` and remote B says that tag `v1.2.3` should mean `feedf00d`, whichever one you pick up first "wins", in general.

The `git reset --hard` is likely the wrong thing to do.  If you're already on a detached `HEAD`, this is like doing a `git checkout` of the given tag, with the side effect of throwing away any work that has not yet been committed.  If you are on a branch name, this alters the stored hash ID in that branch name, which is probably wrong.

Overall, it is probably more sensible to run `git fetch --tags`, without `--all`, to fetch from the *current* remote, or to pick a specific remote to trust; or if there's only one remote, `git fetch --tags` will use that one remote and then `--all` is unnecessary.  Then, having done that, use `git checkout tags/v2.11.0` or `git switch --detach tags/v2.11.0`, which will complain if there is uncommitted work.

Comment: Big Thanks for your long and very detailed answer. I forgot an information in my question above. I want the submodules to be on the master branch too. They should be on the master branch at the commit which belongs to the superproject tag.

Comment: @crappidy: there are multiple repositories, so you should qualify this: *which* `master`? If you want the submodule repository to run `git fetch` to its own remote and then use its updated `origin/master`, the user-oriented Git command to do ... well, not *quite* this, is `git submodule update --remote`. The `--remote` is equivalent to `git submodule foreach` with a `git fetch` and then a `git checkout <hash>` where `<hash>` is from a specified branch, but the branch isn't necessarily `master`: it's the one that comes from the `branch` setting in the superproject.

Comment: See [the `git submodule` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) for all the gory details, and note that it tends to require repeated re-reading as you decode each layer of the complex submodule configuration stuff.